# Change label background of selected radio in Angular 12

Tags: angular, radio-group, angular12

Whats the best approach to detect which radio has been selected in the following example?

```
<label for="apple">
    <input id="apple" type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" class=""/>
    <span>Apple </span>
    <SomeComponent>
</label>
<label for="mango"> 
   <input id="mango" type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" class=""/>
   <span>Mango </span>
   <AnotherComponent>    
</label>
```

I want to be able to add a background to the selected label using ngClass. I could also use that variable for other things (such as disabling 'SomeComponent' or 'AnotherComponent' in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update a variable when change event fires for each radio and then use ngClass to apply background color to each label based on the variable's value.

Here you have an example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypidy6?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is a simple enough approach. I guess if I need another radio box then could use an ngFor to keep track of indexes and which one is selected.